# Mouse click chrome from c# app

Tags: c#, google-chrome

I'm trying to build a simple app which all it does is to click a specific spot in the Chrome browser.

I start the process from the code by

```
var proc = Process.Start("chrome.exe",
"https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=" + textBox1.Text);
```

And now I want to mouse click on it.

This is what I have tried

```
    private void buttonGO_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IntPtr iHandle = FindWindow(null, "Chrome");
        if (iHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            SetForegroundWindow(iHandle);
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            moveToPos(30000, 19500);
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            performClick(30000, 19500);
        }
    }

    private void performClick(uint x, uint y)
    {
        SetCursorPos(x, y);
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, x, y, 0, UIntPtr.Zero);
        Thread.Sleep(200);
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, x, y, 0, UIntPtr.Zero);
    }
    private void moveToPos(uint x, uint y)
    {
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, x, y, 0, UIntPtr.Zero);
    }
```

But it cant find the window.
Does anyone know this?

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this:

```
private void buttonGO_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Get all chrome processes
    Process[] chromeProcesses = Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome");
    Process uiProcess = null;
    foreach (Process process in chromeProcesses)
    {
        // Assuming you've opened chrome only once, the UI process will have MainWindowHandle, so get its reference and break out of loop
        if (process.MainWindowHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            uiProcess = process;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (uiProcess == null)
        return;

    // Do your stuff here
    IntPtr iHandle = uiProcess.MainWindowHandle;
    if (iHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        SetForegroundWindow(iHandle);
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        moveToPos(30000, 19500);
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        performClick(30000, 19500);
    }
}
```

Also, if you want to perform a lot of automated mouse click actions, try AutoIt3 library, it's perfect for such things.